# Rendered Fontsに適用されるフォントについて

Tags: css

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
あるサイトでfont-familyがsans-serifが適用されているにも関わらずMeiryoで描画されていました。
cssの中を確認した所font-familyはsans-serifしか設定されていません。

sans-serifが無かった場合Meiryoで描画されるのかと思い、
同じように作ってみたのですが、MeiryoではなくMS PGothicで描画されてしまいました。

Rendered Fontsに適用されるフォントはfont-family以外何か別の方法があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sans-serif`というのはフォントの種類を指定するためのキーワードです。`sans-serif`という名前のフォントが存在するわけではありません。これは`generic family`と呼ばれ、他にも`cursive`や`monospace`などのキーワードがあります。

実際にRendered Fontsに適用されるフォントはブラウザ側でキーワードから自動的に判断されます。chromeの場合は`chrome://settings/fonts`を開くとキーワードとフォントの関連付けを変更できます。